# Powershell Rename-Item Multiple In to 1 out and case sensitivity

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

The following code works beautifully:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Videos\Movies\ -File -Include *.avi,*.mp4,*.mkv -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("DVDRIP","DVD") }
```

Now, 2 questions:

1. Anyway I can input multiple words to replace to DVD?  Here is what I was thinking:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Videos\Movies\ -File -Include *.avi,*.mp4,*.mkv -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace("DVDRIP|DVDR|DVD5|DVD9","DVD") }
   ```

   I have tried this and other variations, but I just can't figure it out.
2. How can I make the code NOT case sensitive so I don't have multiple lines trying to catch the possible different spellings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a regex-pattern with a normal text-replace method. Try `-replace` which is made for regex. `-replace` is also case-insensitive by default.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Videos\Movies\ -File -Include *.avi,*.mp4,*.mkv -Recurse |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "DVDRIP|DVDR|DVD5|DVD9","DVD" }
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!  I knew it was something stupid I was missing!  This works great, thanks so much!